# Node js: piping data to multiple streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe

I'm using the node gm middleware which has a method for resizing and piping the resized image. When I resize an image I need to cache it and stream the image back to the user. Can I do both of these at the same time?

To be clear what I want to do is `gm(file).resize(...).pipe -> writeStream.pipe -> response`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `writeStream.pipe()` because `pipe()` is for Readable streams. You'd have to have pipe twice like:

```
var resize = gm(file).resize(...).stream();
resize('data', function(data) {
    response.write(data);
    write_stream.write(data);
});
resize('end', function(data) {
    response.end(data);
    write_stream.end(data);
});
```

Comment: This really gave me some insight. My only issues now is when I read the stream twice I get nothing.